# Is there a View function in Python to rotate plots like in Matlab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have an image that I would like to rotate. Namely, exchange the `x` and `y` axes. It is of a spectrogram. The basic code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Sxx, f, t, im = plt.specgram(dataArray, NFFT=2**8, Fs = 100, noverlap = 128)

plt.show()
```

This is what gets produced:

[image]

Does Python have a function that rotates the image 90 degrees as easily as the `View` function does in Matlab?

***UPDATE***

I've learned that `plt.specgram` can take all `kwargs` that `imshow` does. I still couldn't find any that would rotate the image, though. Anyone know?

***UPDATE 2***

I found [here](http://snippets-of-code.blogspot.com/2014/03/rotating-spectrogram.html) and confirmed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html#inputarg_freqloc) that Matlab has an argument option `freqloc` that can be used to exchange where the axes are drawn, but I can't locate the Python equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scipy [rotate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html) to rotate your data (from the array point of view). The following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

X, Y = np.meshgrid(range(100), range(100))
im = X**2 + Y**2
imrot45 = ndimage.rotate(im, 45)
imrot90 = ndimage.rotate(im, 90)

f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)

ax1.imshow(im, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest')
ax2.imshow(imrot45, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest')
ax3.imshow(imrot90, origin='lower', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

, results in this:

[image: rotate imshow data for matplotlib plot]

Depending on your data you may also want to try `im.T` (transpose) or numpy [rot90](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html).

I also recently, in another question, gave a recipe to rotate the figure if you prefer to do this. Check the following question:

[Rotate a figure but not the legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462130/rotate-a-figure-but-not-the-legend/37467828#37467828)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can't see to get this to work with the `plt.specgram` function, though.

Comment: Sorry @Lou, it seems specgram has a behavior very different from the common matplotlib objects. I'm saying this because even with the second solution (where I rotate the figure) the plot remains the same. Have you considered using [imshow to build a specgram](http://www.frank-zalkow.de/en/code-snippets/create-audio-spectrograms-with-python.html). If the answer is not useful I'll delete it by tomorrow. Sorry for not being able to help more.

Comment: I'll take a look at that link. It seems he's building his own spectrogram function, which will probably be the way to go to have the axes how I want them. Thanks for your help!